# Adding a Column to Import in Flat File Source Editor

Tags: ssis

I have a CSV file that I use a SSIS package to import into SQL Server.  I am looking at the 'Flat File Source Editor' under 'Data Flow' and I see a list of 'External Column' with the matching 'Output Column'.  If I have a new column in my CSV file, how would I add that to be included in the import?  I don't see an option to add a new column in the Flat File Source Editor.

Flat File Source Editor view:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Usually when you open the editor it will update automatically if the CSV file structure has changed in any way. Have you tried it and did it work ?

Comment: @Pondlife It doesn't recognize the new column and the package fails when I run it with the new column on the CSV file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the flat file source that you need to change, it is the flat file connection manager. Your source references a connection manager. You should see that connection manager listed in the 'Connection Managers' tab below the design surface. Edit the column list on that connection manager (or refresh from your source file). After doing that you should see the new column listed in the Flat File Source component.